# Laravel Multi-auth (multiple user tables) from same login

Tags: laravel, authentication

I plan to develop a system that has three user types (admin, business, personal). I want to have each user types information stored in a separate table for easy access and to reduce the number of blank fields (if they were all in one table).

Having looked at multiple Multi-auth packages available for Laravel, they all appear to be insisting on an approach with URLs like the following:

- /admin/login
- /business/login
- /personal/login

Ideally, I would like to take an approach where the standard Laravel Auth /login can be used meaning that all users log in from the same page.

My knowledge of Laravel is limited so all and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach is to have one `users` table which has the ID/email/username (as primary key), login credentials and user types for **all** the users which will be logging into the system. The information however can be stored in separate tables for each type, referencing the foreign key.
After authenticating the user, then you can decide what to do with the user based on the user type.

If you store login credentials in multiple tables, that's data redundancy. Unless you want the same email/username to have more than one user type, but then during login, the user has to decide which user type they want to log into (maybe by selecting a dropdown option).

---

**Update:** about user roles

If you need to simply redirect users after logging in, use `$redirectTo`. Or if you need to decide what to do with the users depending on the roles after logging, you can make use of `authenticated()` method (add this method if it's not already there, it will overwrite the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait) inside your `AuthController`/`LoginController`.

Throughout your application, I'd suggest assigning [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware) to [route groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-groups) to restrict routes based on user roles. And yes, in your views and controllers you can use something like `if(Auth::user()->hasRole('business'))` when needed, but first you'll need to create the `hasRole()` method in your *User model*. If you feel it's getting complicated, you may try packages like [laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) and [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust). I haven't tried them though :)

Comment: Perfect, I have been trialing this and things seem to be working so far! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @SeanTreanor Glad to be of help :)

Comment: I have another question if you don't mind me asking.

If I take this approach in the system, will I need to work with guards or can I just continuously use a function to check the user's role before presenting them with information?

For example:

if (Auth()->user()->role == "business") {
    // show if business
} else if (Auth()->user()->role == "admin") {
   // show if admin
}

Comment: @SeanTreanor You can just use a function like you mentioned to check roles instead of guards. I've updated the answer about user roles. You can mark this as answered if it answers your question :) Cheers

Comment: You @sykez are a saviour! I’m new to stackoverflow but I think I’ve set the question as answered! Thanks again pal! :)